# Apt-get couldn’t find package

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have just launched my first EC2 instance and chose an Ubuntu image to start from, since it's quite well documented.

However, I am trying to install the Redis package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/redis-server

Maybe I am not googling properly or just stupid since the weekend is approaching, but I'll keep getting errors:

```
root@ip-10-229-123-199:~# sudo apt-get install redis-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package redis-server
```

I'll assume that I need to add a repository or something to Ubuntu to help it find the package I want, but how do I do it? I can only find graphical guides which doesn't help me too much since I am using SSH.

Edit:
After some help from Bart (many thanks to you!), this occurs instead:

```
root@ip-10-229-123-199:~# sudo apt-get install redis-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Package redis-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package redis-server has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the repos, I'd look in Synaptic. System->administration->synaptic package manager. Search there (after a reload to update package lists) and see if the package is in the list. Otherwise for different applications you may need to search for a .Deb file to install or google for "ubuntu" and the package name to find installation instructions.

If the EC2 instance is command line only, you should probably start looking [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine), as it has links to other sources as well as a tutorial on repo management from the command line from the Ubuntu online manual.

Comment: Hi Bart, How do I do that with ssh?

Comment: Just added a link to command line management of repos :-) Let us know if that has information that helps.

Comment: You may not have universe repos enabled. That link should have information on enabling it and updating them.

Comment: Great stuff! Now I'll managed to get a step further. What about this: "Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.3.6-0ubuntu20.5" ? Can I update Lib6?

Comment: It should update dependencies necessary by the .deb. Have you updated installed items already? sudo apt-get update & then run sudo apt-get upgrade?

Comment: Checking my install (lucid) I have libc6 of 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.

Comment: Hi Bart, did that and now another error occurs - "No installation candidate" - updated my original post. Thanks alot!

Comment: Weird...implies that the package isn't directly available, but Googling Ubuntu's site doesn't indicate it's separate. This site has a way to install under Jaunty http://pragmatig.com/2010/02/22/installing-redis-server-on-ubuntu-jaunty/

Comment: See if this helps. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/3487

Comment: If you end up downloading from the package repo on Ubuntu directly as suggested at the end, substitute your release instead of edgy. That's fairly old. Perhaps your list of packages isn't updated completely?

Comment: This might help you with commands to narrow down package names and searches from the command line. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-debian-package-management-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: Thanks man! Your last link with the Jaunty approach did the trick. You're amazing!

Comment: Glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 3):

You should look at `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

A thorough tutorial can be found in the Ubuntu documentation.

[Repositories Using the Command Line - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)